# Unable to access registry key « Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process Jet »

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, odbc, iis-7.5

I have been trying to work with old Classic ASP on Windows 7 (IIS 7.5) for days now. Always running into more troubles. Now, I finally have it done, but there's still a big problem : I can't open the Acess .mdb file. I use the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) as mentioned in [this tutorial](http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=6) I've followed. The error I get is the following:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access driver] Unable to access registry
>   key « Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process Jet »

Googled my way to a lot of explanations. I ended up granting rights to IIS\DefaultAppPool to a lot of places, but still no luck. I always get this error message.

Here's my connection string just in case:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bd\mydatabase.mdb
```

Can anyone help me with this one? Thanks!

Comment: I used a different connection `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\serverName\shareName\folder\myAccess2007file.accdb;` -- http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: No luck with that either...  But the message is not the same. Now it's something about the filename. But the filename (at least the mdb path) is OK. If I copy it in Windows Explorer, the mdb opens.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: You need to add permissions to the IUSR account. Try following [this guide](http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/setting-permissions-to-access-database-step-by-step-guide-96087.html). I've also noticed possible typo in your connection string: is it really `\mysite\bd\mydatabase.mdb` or did you mean `\mysite\db\mydatabase.mdb`? When the database file is not found, Access won't throw meaningful error like "file can't be found" but rather this cryptic error you see.

Comment: By the way when you reply please use `@` to notify e.g. @Shadow so that the person you reply to will get notification.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [“General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) …” from Access ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26244425/12892).